# hist function doesn't display anything

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, histogram

The `hist` function doesn't display anything.

Why does this happen? It seems that the code is ok.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))

loans[loans["credit.policy"]==1]["fico"].hist(bins=35, color="blue",
                                            label="Credit Policy = 1",
                                            alpha=0.6)
loans[loans["credit.policy"]==0]["fico"].hist(bins=35, color="red",
                                            label="Credit Policy = 0",
                                            alpha=0.6)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: here is the output]

Comment: Maybe there is no data to plot? Did you look at the output of `loans["credit.policy"]==1`?

Comment: Why is `matlab` tagged here?